# How to get the ID of a clicked control in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a toggle div and a button, when i clicking button show/hide toggle button.

I use this code for, when clicking anywhere of the page hide the toggle div.

```
  $(document).click(function () {
             var $el = $(".Search");

             // toggle div
             if ($el.is(":visible")) {
                 // fade out
                 $(".Search").toggle("slow");
             }
         });
```

My problem is: When clicking on control in toggle button , this function run and hide toggle div.

I want to get id of a clicked control. if control is toggle div don't run this function.

Comment: Use `$(this).(".Search").toggle("slow");`

Comment: You don't get good answers becasue you cannot describe your problem correctly. I can help you if you want. I am also Persian. You can describe the problem for me, and I'll edit your question (and I'll post an answer if I could help, of course).

Comment: @MD.Unicorn : Thanks, i get answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you have to `.stopPropagation()`:

```
 $('togglebtn').click(function(e){ //<----put your btn's class or id
   e.stopPropagation(); // <---------this will stop the event to bubble to parent
   // your stuff to hide and show.
 });

 $(document).click(function () {
     var $el = $(".Search");
     if ($el.is(":visible")) {
       $(".Search").toggle("slow");
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here something is missing with you. 
You should use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("button[name='give the name of button on which you want to toggle']").click(function(){
     var $el = $(".Search");

         // toggle div
         if ($el.is(":visible")) {
             // fade out
             $(".Search").toggle("slow");
         }
       });
     });
```

This will surely work for you. I hope is that which you are asking.

Cheers.